# Scroll isn't working on my HTML/CSS website

Tags: html, css

I think the mistake is in my CSS, I can't scroll and I don't get the scroll thing on the right.

```
Here's my CSS code: https://pastebin.com/pRgX5Pgn

Here's my HTML code: https://pastebin.com/akeKjHLS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tjenare! :D

Removing `overflow: hidden` on body enables scrolling again.

```css
html, body
{
    height:100%;
}

body
{
    margin:0;
    background-color: #292929;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}

nav
{
    position: absolute;
    top:50px;
    right: 25%;
    left: 0;
    width: 319px;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

nav a
{
    position: relative;
    width: 33.333%;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    color: #949494;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    transition: 0.2s ease color;
}

nav a:before, nav a:after
{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: 0.2s ease transform;
}

nav a:before
{
    top: 0;
    left: 10px;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
}

nav a:after
{
    top: 5px;
    left: 18px;
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px
}

nav a:nth-child(1):before
{
    background-color: yellow;
}

nav a:nth-child(1):after
{
    background-color: red;
}

nav a:nth-child(2):before
{
    background-color: #00e2ff;
}

nav a:nth-child(2):after
{
    background-color: #89ff00;
}

nav a:nth-child(3):before
{
    background-color: purple;
}

nav a:nth-child(3):after
{
    background-color: palevioletred;
}

nav a:nth-child(4):before
{
    background-color: rgb(23, 255, 93);
}

nav a:nth-child(4):after
{
    background-color:  purple;
}

nav a:nth-child(5):before
{
    background-color: rgb(27, 23, 255);
}

nav a:nth-child(5):after
{
    background-color: rgb(218, 205, 36);
}

nav a:nth-child(6):before
{
    background-color:rgb(40, 150, 126);
}

nav a:nth-child(6):after
{
    background-color: rgb(219, 58, 219);
}

#indicator
{
    position: absolute;
    left:110px;
    right:50%;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: 0.2s ease left;
}

nav a:hover
{
    color: #fff;
}

nav a:hover:before, nav a:hover:after
{
    transform: scale(1);
}

nav a:nth-child(1):hover ~ #indicator
{
    background: linear-gradient(130deg, yellow, red);
}

nav a:nth-child(2):hover ~ #indicator
{
    left: 14%;
    background: linear-gradient(130deg, #00e2ff, #89ff00);
}

nav a:nth-child(3):hover ~ #indicator
{
    left: 33%;
    background: linear-gradient(130deg, purple, palevioletred);
}

nav a:nth-child(4):hover ~ #indicator
{
    left: 51%;
    background: linear-gradient(130deg, rgb(23, 255, 93), rgb(170, 20, 70));
}

nav a:nth-child(5):hover ~ #indicator
{
    left: 67%;
    background: linear-gradient(130deg, rgb(27, 23, 255), rgb(218, 205, 36));
}

nav a:nth-child(6):hover ~ #indicator
{
    left: 86%;
    background: linear-gradient(130deg, rgb(40, 150, 126), rgb(219, 58, 219));
}

 
/* Furlundskolans logga längst upp i head */
.furulundlogga {
  height:50px;
  float:relative;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-left:15px; 
}
 
/* program menyn */
 
.byggbanner {
  display:block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top:25px;
  width:1220px;
  height:200px;
  text-align:center;
}

.bygger {
  display:block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-top:20px;
  width:400px;
  height:auto;
  text-align:right;
}

.dab {
  display:block;
  margin-top:20px;
  width:400px;
  height:auto;
  text-align:left;

}
.stycket {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image-using-css/ 

https://hostpapasupport.com/align-float-images-website/
*/
```

```html
html>
  <title> Furulundskolan 2020</title>
 
  <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylebygg.css">
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/HP0QW41/furulundskolan.png" class="furulundlogga">
</head>
<body> 
  
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 
<nav>
  <a href="index.html">HEM</a>
  <a href="program.html">VÅRA PROGRAM</a>
  <a href="#">ELEV PÅ FURULUND</a>
  <a href="#">STUDERA HOS OSS</a>
  <a href="#">OM FURULUND</a>
  <a href="#">KONTAKTA OSS</a>
  <div id="indicator"></div>
</nav>
  
  <img class="byggbanner" src="https://www.storel.se/medias/sys_Storel/root/hb2/hc6/9622955393054/rexelBuildingAutomationBanner.jpg">
 
  <div class="stycket">
    <p class="dab">"Bygg- och anläggningsprogrammet vänder sig till dig som tänker dig ett framtida arbete inom Bygg- och anläggningsbranschen. Här får du prova på flera olika hantverk och i åk 2 specialisera dig i ditt inriktningsval. Det är ett plus om du är händig, har sinne för färg och form, samt kan arbeta självständigt. Du bör inte vara rädd för höjder eller obekväma arbetsförhållanden då detta ingår i utbildningen samt i ditt framtida yrkesval" </p> 
    <img class="bygger" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/BX5YGoBBAbL4yGfrzKIRXz-11FBy0azTP3facU9vPQDwKffc-EIb5ibK8UY9jtoUIDmRL2VKWBQzpoLaWtdHyApKonxGz1Y-X9YZCsYPuIVf88vm8oF2pdVlZI-ACWEGJn8ygWia8Rr70zFnHL3m9A7-UB0FKr1nqYC4KOwnrxRB_Q1PrHj3L8dXHDoQR36BD_vmX7G2_J1cBM4StcYqkUEtmmX02uMtUcpsXIC1rUfs061HfDwBxRLHf0kDxkvtTsYcacnTCH7Kl6tUhPyuO_FM-8ypQvrCy8wp2X0-0S4TryyM0x01nvgS4ighnczeD6R7tqO4rQvkfNXQ_LBxUq2GFSGaqFdyR2gqLKqpiDy--6gNspeuByr1iv4wdSDqSXWwN_OcssQjaP_BqGXLdbOsZg8lZyo4y_g3dz8PhxFFlmhA_yVGYb-wX9rgvkMbr8P3AFRE9M8XIB7ZqMI0SvluMDyDg8YIh8Wk6_Dt9KmdZE7Jd1RCPyU4mRNStLbsGLY7jdLcIbf5PmGDe_x22VLlSin8JfISBOikpK0GscWhD9x-3turmsj9oqS8CYo4NfhfAqUh054ddvHKoCIgluTEB9EyTWnTxbdYOLFCnSWkPa-_6gyIBW6lZd24Gzlg-d33S7dgQ_NA4hhy_33WtCY_YuOXvjxbC7IRtCxQeb1d92NxFXnTJX1DTXzq0A=w614-h454-no?authuser=0">
  </div>
 
</body>
 
 
</html>
```

Comment: Tusen tack för hjälpen, greatly appricated, höll på att tappa vettet kunde inte sätta fingret på vad felet var! :3

Comment: Ingen fara!! :D